# nginx reverse proxy with subpage as parameter

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'll try to handle all requests at my server URL's in nginx to another service at my server. The service shouldn't be visible from outside, so I will use the reverse proxy functionality of nginx.
So the requests to nginx should be for example:

- https://foo.url => http://localhost:2424
- https://foo.url/page1 => http://localhost:2424?_=/page1
- https://foo.url/sub1/page2 => http://localhost:2424?_=/sub1/page2

Currently I don't need get parameters, but of course it would be nice if they'd work too, i.e.:

- https://foo.url/page1?xxx=abc => http://localhost:2424?_=/page1&xxx=abc

Currently my config is like that:

```
...
    location / {
            gzip off;

            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/;
            proxy_set_header Proxy "";
...
```

What's of course don't redirect the subpages. But following wasn't working too:

```
...

    location /(.*) {
    # location ~ /(.*) { # I tried this too

    ...
     
           proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/?_=$1;
...
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the URI before it gets processed by the `proxy_pass` statement, by adding a `rewrite...break;` statement inside the `location /` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example:

```
location / {
    ...
    rewrite ^(/.*)$ /?_=$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you. It is working, but not as I wish to. There were two other problems (one of them I didn't face):

1. In the url of the browser I see the new URL too (foo.url/?_=page1) what I won't have.
2. I hadn't in mind that I need some URL's in normal way forwarded, i.e. http://foo.url/scripts => http://localhost:1234/scripts

The last one I fixed by adding

```
  rewrite ^/script(/.*)$ /script/$1 break;
  rewrite ^/(/.*) /?_=$1 break;
```

But I'm not sure if it is the right way or if there is something like "all, but not this one"